# Managing multiple projects with github

Tags: git, github, git-branch

I have Multiple projects `ex : 20 projects` , and i have an account on github for each project i create repository `20 project = 20 repository`.

I look for a way to manage my projects in github but i don't want to set each project on repository , that will take more repository and not efficient after i got maybe another `20 project` that will take `40 repository`.

How i can manage the projects in github to take `fewest number of repository` ?

Comment: I think this is indeed the right way. You can avoid creating new repositories by creating a new branch for each project.
However, for branches you won't be able to control user rights per branch.

Comment: I am assuming that you are working as a software consultant, and manage code for clients on github. Your main problem is that according to github's pricing model you want to use as less as possible number of repositories. One solution in that case is to create a repository per client and have a separate branch for each of his projects.

Comment: Last, but very importantly I don't think this question is right for this forum.

Comment: I read that branch used for new feature for master branch , Is that way branching projects on one repository doing effectively ? The commit on project (branch) will commit without pull request ?

Comment: I write this question here because i read many questions for github on stackoverflow about managing , so i write this question  here.

Comment: You need to have an empty/default branch. Each time you need to create a branch for a 'new' project you will create a branch from this empty branch.